# withMathJax inside modalDialog table

Tags: r, shiny, mathjax

I am trying to include LateX formulas inside a table and I am using the MathJack library to do so. Everthing is working smoothly outside a modalDialog, but when the table is produced within the modalDialog, it does not show as expected. I guess it has do to with what is written in the help page "It only needs to be called once in an app unless the content is rendered after the page is loaded, e.g. via renderUI(), in which case we have to call it explicitly every time we write math expressions to the output.". But I can't figure out how to solve the issue.

Here is a repex :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    withMathJax(), 
    actionButton("open", "Open")))


server <- function(input, output, session){  
  
  output$mytable <- renderTable({  
    df <- data.frame(A = c(HTML("$$\\alpha+\\beta$$"), "$$\\alpha+\\gamma$$", "$$\\alpha+\\lambda$$"),B = c(111111, 3333333, 3123.233))  
    df  
  }, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$open, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      withMathJax(),
      h2("$$\\mbox{My Math example }\\sqrt{2}$$"),
      tableOutput('mytable')))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly, that works like this:

```
  observeEvent(input$open, {
    showModal(withMathJax(modalDialog(
      h2("$$\\mbox{My Math example }\\sqrt{2}$$"),
      withMathJax(tableOutput('mytable')))))
  })
```

## EDIT

Since there are some problems with this solution, here is a solution using **KaTeX** instead of **MathJax**:

```r
library(shiny)

js <- " 
$(document).on('shiny:value', function(event) {
  if(event.name === 'mytable'){
    // h2 element
    var $h2 = $('#title');
    var title = $h2.html();
    var matches_title = title.match(/(%%+[^%]+%%)/g);
    var i, code;
    for(i=0; i<matches_title.length; i++){
      code = matches_title[i].slice(2,-2);
      title = title.replace(matches_title[i], katex.renderToString(code));
    }
    $h2.html(title);
    $h2.css('visibility', 'visible');
    // table:
    var matches = event.value.match(/(%%+[^%]+%%)/g);
    var newvalue = event.value;
    for(i=0; i<matches.length; i++){
      code = matches[i].slice(2,-2);
      newvalue = newvalue.replace(matches[i], katex.renderToString(code));
    }
    event.value = newvalue;
  }
})
" 

css <- "#mytable td:nth-child(3) {display: none;}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.2/dist/katex.min.css", integrity="sha384-MlJdn/WNKDGXveldHDdyRP1R4CTHr3FeuDNfhsLPYrq2t0UBkUdK2jyTnXPEK1NQ", crossorigin="anonymous"),
    tags$script(defer="", src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.2/dist/katex.min.js", integrity="sha384-VQ8d8WVFw0yHhCk5E8I86oOhv48xLpnDZx5T9GogA/Y84DcCKWXDmSDfn13bzFZY", crossorigin="anonymous"),
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    tags$style(HTML(css))
  ),
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  br(),
  actionButton("open", "Open")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){  
  
  output$mytable <- renderTable({ 
    data.frame(
      A = c("%%\\alpha+\\beta%%", "%%\\alpha+\\gamma%%", "%%\\alpha+\\lambda%%"),
      B = c(111111, 3333333, 3123.233),
      ` ` = rep(input$open, 3),
      check.names = FALSE
    ) 
  }, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
  
  
  observeEvent(input$open, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      h2(
        id = "title", 
        style = "visibility: hidden;", 
        "%%\\boxed{Math}\\sqrt{2}%%"
      ),
      tableOutput("mytable")
    ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that I include a reactive column in the dataframe:

```
` ` = rep(input$open, 3)
```

That's because the KaTeX rendering works only one time if I don't do that. Then I hide this column with some CSS.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works on a first intention. Unfortunately when I close and reopen the model, it does not work. 
Also I have this message when opening the app : "Loading web-font TeX/Math/Italic" which takes a while. For this time, the formulas do not render properly (and it ends up very blurry).
Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: @Bambs You're right. See my edit.

Comment: This is so good, thanks ! One last question, would it be easily convertible into a DT format ?

Comment: @Bambs I think this would even be easier with DT, by using the `render` option.

Comment: @Bambs See https://stackoverflow.com/q/71207531/1100107

Comment: This is really cool, thanks for your great help @Stéphane !