# LaTeX in DT::datatable

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, latex, dt

I have a `datatable` in a modal of a Shiny app and I want to render some LaTeX in a column. How could I do?

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  br(),
  actionButton("open", "Open")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){  
  
  output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      data.frame(
        A = c("$$\\alpha+\\beta$$", "$$\\alpha+\\gamma$$", "$$\\alpha+\\lambda$$"),
        B = c(111111, 3333333, 3123.233)
      ) 
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["open"]], {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      DTOutput("mytable")
    ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using **KaTeX**. Maybe it's possible with `withMathjax` but IMHO **KaTeX** is better.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

renderKaTeX <- c(
  "function(data, type, row, meta){",
  "  if(type === 'display'){",
  "    data = katex.renderToString(data);",
  "  }",
  "  return data;",
  "}"
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$link(
      rel = "stylesheet", 
      href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.2/dist/katex.min.css", 
      integrity = "sha384-MlJdn/WNKDGXveldHDdyRP1R4CTHr3FeuDNfhsLPYrq2t0UBkUdK2jyTnXPEK1NQ", 
      crossorigin = "anonymous"
    ),
    tags$script(
      defer = "", 
      src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.15.2/dist/katex.min.js", 
      integrity = "sha384-VQ8d8WVFw0yHhCk5E8I86oOhv48xLpnDZx5T9GogA/Y84DcCKWXDmSDfn13bzFZY", 
      crossorigin = "anonymous"
    )
  ),
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  br(),
  actionButton("open", "Open")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){  
  
  output[["mytable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      data.frame(
        A = c("\\alpha+\\beta", "\\alpha+\\gamma", "\\alpha+\\lambda"),
        B = c(111111, 3333333, 3123.233)
      ),
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = 1, render = JS(renderKaTeX))
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input[["open"]], {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      DTOutput("mytable")
    ))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]